# Input text shows in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you put the result of this jsfiddle to full size so the and click the search icon so the input field shows, if you type in the field in chrome you can see the text, but in firefox the text does type but you cannot see it?

http://jsfiddle.net/vxkp6beg/

If I remove padding in bootstrap I can see the text a bit but the field is no longer full height and the text is cut off.

```
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    padding: 25px 12px; # here
    font-size: 18pt;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

I have also tried but this just makes the input field larger.

```
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
```

Is there any way to fix this for Firefox or preferably, for all other browsers?

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding is taking up the entire element.  You can keep the padding-left, just remove top padding and set height to 50px (25px padding x 2)  http://jsfiddle.net/vxkp6beg/7/:

```
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
        padding: 0 12px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 18pt;
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the element altogether by setting the attribute `display` to `none`.

`navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    padding: 25px 12px; # here
    font-size: 18pt;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}`

Why don't you *just* use the attribute `opacity`?

Comment: `display` is set to `none` because there is first a button which shows and expands the input field, this gets removed once you click the button to show.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the padding. Remove the padding or remove the fixed height on the element.